# Fill formula down till last row in column

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I'm trying to draw down the formula that's in cell M3 to the end of the data set.

I'm using column L as my base to determine the last cell with data. My formula is a concatenation of two cells with a text comma in-between them.

My formula is =G3&","&L3

I want Excel to draw down this formula so

Cell M4 would be =G4&","&L4
Cell M5 would be =G5&","&L5 and so on.

My code:

```
Range("$M$3").Formula = Range("G3") & (",") & Range("L3")

Dim Lastrow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Lastrow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("M4").FormulaR1C1 = Range("G4") & (",") & Range("L4")
Range("M4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M4:M" & Lastrow)
ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

My output is pulling down the text values from cell M3 all the way down to the end of the data set. I've searched around for several hours trying to look for a fix, but can't find one that is trying to accomplish what I'm going for.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

It's a one liner actually. No need to use `.Autofill`

```
Range("M3:M" & LastRow).Formula = "=G3&"",""&L3"
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes me regret not asking sooner! :)

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I am trying to use same formula in my macro, but it giving error
 Range("J5:J" & LastRow).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""TOTAL"",RC[-9])),TRIM(LEFT(RC[-9],FIND("" "",RC[-9]&""""))),""""),z43.xlsx!R2C2:R137C5,3,FALSE),"""")"
 
Run time error 1004:
Method range object _global failed.

Comment: Can you please help me what could be the reason? i am new to this excel and macro

Comment: Nitish, first put the formula in cell J5 and check if it is working there and then simply copy the formula across :)

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, you may use **FillDown**

```
Range("M3") = "=G3&"",""&L3": Range("M3:M" & LastRow).FillDown
```

Answer (score 10):

For people with a similar question and find this post (like I did);
you can do this even without lastrow if your dataset is formatted as a table.

```
Range("tablename[columnname]").Formula = "=G3&"",""&L3"
```

Making it a true one liner. Hope it helps someone!

Comment: This answer looks good, in fact I have my data formatted as a table, but my formulas are like "=DATE(YEAR('Raw Data'!$N2),MONTH('Raw Data'!$N2),DAY('Raw Data'!$N2))" on row 2, of course in row 3 it changes to "=DATE(YEAR('Raw Data'!$N3),MONTH('Raw Data'!$N3),DAY('Raw Data'!$N3))" and so on. How to apply this solution to all lines? Oh, I almost forgot, I have three columns with formulas, and I need to fill down all three columns.

Comment: @EduardoChavarría The formula changes automatically to the other rows. The formula entered in the VBA code should only be for the first row, you can lock rows or columns with the $ sign like regular formulas. However this code does not automatically expand the table itself. So the table should already have as much rows as the raw data, which is always the case if the data is already in the same table. If not you can add "table.Resize desiredSize" based on the size/length of the raw data

Comment: I will try that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Wonderful answer! I needed to fill in the empty cells in a column where there were titles in cells that applied to the empty cells below until the next title cell.

I used your code above to develop the code that is below my example sheet here. I applied this code as a macro ctl/shft/D to rapidly run down the column copying the titles.

--- Example Spreadsheet ------------
Title1 is copied to rows 2 and 3; Title2 is copied to cells below it in rows 5 and 6. After the second run of the Macro the active cell is the Title3 cell.

```
 ' **row** **Column1**        **Column2**
 '    1     Title1         Data 1 for title 1
 '    2                    Data 2 for title 1
 '    3                    Data 3 for title 1
 '    4     Title2         Data 1 for title 2
 '    5                    Data 2 for title 2
 '    6                    Data 3 for title 2
 '    7   Title 3          Data 1 for title 3
```

----- CopyDown code ----------

```
Sub CopyDown()
Dim Lastrow As String, FirstRow As String, strtCell As Range
'
' CopyDown Macro
' Copies the current cell to any empty cells below it.   
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+D
'
    Set strtCell = ActiveCell
    FirstRow = strtCell.Address
' Lastrow is address of the *list* of empty cells
    Lastrow = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown).Offset(-1, 0)).Address
'   MsgBox Lastrow
    Range(Lastrow).Formula = strtCell.Formula

    Range(Lastrow).End(xlDown).Select
 End Sub
```