# VBA Fill first row under header

Tags: vba, excel

Pretty simple problem that is frustrating me. I have this filtered column in my worksheet where Type is the header name:

```
   AO
1  Type
55 blank
62 blank
63 blank
65 blank
```

I'm trying to fill everything past Type in this filtered column with the text 'A'

My attempt so far:

```
LastRow = Range("AO" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AO:AO" & LastRow).Offset(1).Formula = "A"
```

But I can't seem to get this variation to work. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AO2:AO" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "A"
```

After your edit, I would perhaps change the `LastRow` to:

```
LastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

Because if you use `AO` *after* the filter, as you showed, you may have tons of blanks. Then `LastRow` might not set properly.  Using column A (which I'm assuming has the most data?) you can help prevent any errors.

Comment: I think the OP only wants the visible cells to have that data.

Comment: @ScottCraner Correct, I'll add that to my post to clarift

Comment: @ScottCraner - Ah, yeah, I meant to add that. Edited.

Comment: @BruceWayne I get the error of Method 'Range' of 'object_Global' failed. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Googling suggests I need to reference the sheet? But if I were to remove the 2 in AO2 it still fills the column, which confuses me

Comment: @codeninja - Can you edit into your OP how you declared, and define, `LastRow`? I'm assuming it's an integer. Also, yes you should add the sheet name to the start, to be clear. `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AO2:AO" & LastRow)...`

Comment: @BruceWayne I got my original attempt from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788750/vba-to-fill-formula-down-till-last-row-in-column However when I declare the sheet name, the error changes to application defined/object defined error

Comment: @codeninja - See my edit. You might want to tweak how/when you set the `LastRow` as well.