# Excel - copy formula in one field across X columns and down to the last row in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Let's say I had this formula in cell B2

```
=IFERROR(MID($A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A2,"@","|",B$1)),IFERROR(FIND(" ",$A2,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A2,"@","|",B$1))),LEN($A2)+1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($A2,"@","|",B$1))),"")
```

In VBA< how would I copy this down to the last row and across to (and including column P)

I've seen examples where it shows a single column but not multiple e.g. [VBA to fill formula down till last row in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788750/vba-to-fill-formula-down-till-last-row-in-column)

Comment: Try `ThisWorkbook.Worksheet("SheetName").Range("B2","P" & nmbRows).Formula = "Your formula here"` where nmbRows is the number of the last used row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the number of rows is determined by data in column A, then try:

```
Dim lRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    lRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("B2:P" & lRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(MID(RC1,FIND(""|"",SUBSTITUTE(RC1,""@"",""|"",R1C)),IFERROR(FIND("" "",RC1,FIND(""|"",SUBSTITUTE(RC1,""@"",""|"",R1C))),LEN(RC1)+1)-FIND(""|"",SUBSTITUTE(RC1,""@"",""|"",R1C))),"""")"
End With
```