# Adding characters to a cell and autofilling the column in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to add a few characters the values in column A, then having it automatically fill down the rest of the rows that have values.  I've tried a couple variations of code I've found in other threads and gotten the same: Run time error 1004: Method range object _global failed.

Here are the codes I've tried:

```
Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34)&CHAR(44)"
```

and

```
Range("B1") = "=CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34)&CHAR(44)": Range("B1:B" & LastRow).FillDown
```

Comment: The first works for me, the problem must reside somewhere else in the code.  Please post more of your code, especially where you declare and assign a value to `LastRow`

Comment: Try `Range("B1:B" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=CHAR(34)&RC[-1]&CHAR(34)&CHAR(44)"` But I suspect `LastRow` may be issue as well, or the fact that you do not explicitly state the parent of `Range`

Comment: please post the actual cell formula that you are trying to create

Comment: which line of your code is causing the error?

Comment: I was formulating the code off of this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788750/vba-to-fill-formula-down-till-last-row-in-column

The cell I'm running it on is a blank one in b1. and column a will have a variable amount of rows in it with data.

By not stating the parent, do you mean adding Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Formula = "=CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34)&CHAR(44)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Run time error 1004: Method range object _global failed` will be thrown by the value of `LastRow` being < 1.  You can usually avoid using the `LastRow` variable by using the coding patterns below.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("B1", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Formula = "=CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34)&CHAR(44)"
End With
```

@mooseman brings up a good point.

If you need to get cells based of the last row of another column then you can use `Range.Offset([col],[row])`

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(0, 1).Formula = "=CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34)&CHAR(44)"
End With
```

This method ensures that you are tartgeing the correct column.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
       .EntireRow.Columns("B").Formula = "=CHAR(34)&A1&CHAR(34)&CHAR(44)"
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Unless you need to get the last row in a specific column(s), that may not be the last row of the worksheet.

Comment: @mooseman great point.  Especially considering that the OP is obviously targeting a different column.  Thanks