# How to self reference a cell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 600k rows and want to remove starting and trailing whitespace. I have the following, but it is rather slow:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-1])"
    Range("D1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D4")
    Range("D1:D4").Select
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("C1").Select
End Sub
```

Is there a way that I can apply the function on itself. I would like to avoid running a function in an empty column, then copying the values to the original column.

I tried [VBA to fill formula down till last row in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788750/vba-to-fill-formula-down-till-last-row-in-column) as well as to speed up the formula. I have a few columns to do this with, and wonder if it is possible to only work on column C and trim the whitespace without the extra computations.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does not use a second column and does all the values in Column C.  It moves the values to an array, iterates the array and trims the excess space and overwrites the values in C with the array.

```
Sub macro1()
Dim rng As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet name.

With ws
    rng = .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Value
    For i = LBound(rng) To UBound(rng)
        rng(i, 1) = Application.Trim(rng(i, 1))
    Next i
    .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Value = rng
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I set up some dummy data to try, and came with the error: "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" just as it enters the line where rng is defined

Comment: It works for me without error.  you sure you changed `"Sheet1"` to your sheet name and you are looking in column C?

Comment: Closed VBA and started again. Works now. Don't know why the error above occurred. Odd indeed. Excel :?

Answer (score 0):

Change the code like this so you don't use `Select`. Using `Select` and `Selection` slows everything down horribly.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-1])"
    Range("D1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("D1:D4")
    Columns("D:D").Copy
    Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Columns("D:D").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: can be done in three lines: `Range("D1:D4") .FormulaR1C1 = "=TRIM(RC[-1])"` : `Columns("C:C").Value = Columns("D:D").Value` : `Columns("D:D").ClearContents`

Comment: @ScottCraner worked great, and doesn't slow my system too much! Love it