# VBA Troubleshooting Worksheetfunction and concatenation operators

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I want to copy a formula all the way down a column that gets the amount of days between two passed in dates. I retrieved the Section: "=R3&","&Q3" from another post on StackOverflow
[Fill formula down till last row in column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788750/fill-formula-down-till-last-row-in-column)
I believe it will work for my desired range.

My question has two parts: 
1. Why do I get an error saying "unable to get the days property of the worksheet function class" when I am passing in the right types of variables and the function works in excel with the same variables?

2. I know that '&' is a concatenation operator outside of "" but what does it mean in this case while it is inside a range like so: "&Q3" ?

   ```
   Sub CycleTimeMerge()

   Workbooks("Workbookname.xls").Worksheets("Worksheetname").Activate
   Dim cel As Range
   Dim LastRow As Double
   LastRow = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row
   Debug.Print "LastRow = " & LastRow
   Range("Y2").Value = "Inprocess Days"
   For Each cel In Range("Y3:Y" & LastRow)
   cel.Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Days("=R3&", "&Q3")
   Next cel

   End Sub
   ```

I also believe I could right some of it instead like so

```
'''
Range("Y3:Y" & LastRow).Formula = Application.WorksheetFunction.Days("=R3&", "&Q3")
'''
```

Thanks for your time

Comment: `Range.Formula` expects a *string* representing the formula: `.Formula = "=Days(...)"`.

Comment: `Range("Y3:Y" & LastRow).Formula = "=Days(R3, Q3)"`