# Multiplication of numbers in a range

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to multiply two cell ranges from different sheets and place result in another sheet.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Worksheets("Revenue").Range("A1").Value = "Year"
Worksheets("Revenue").Range("B1").Value = "Revenue"
Worksheets("Revenue").Range("A2:A12").Value = Worksheets("Price").Range("A2:A12").Value
Worksheets("Revenue").Range("B2:B12").Value = CDbl(Worksheets("Price").Range("B2:B12").Value) * CDbl(Worksheets("Demand").Range("B2:B12").Value)
End Sub
```

Numbers in sheet price:
[image: Prices]

Numbers in sheet Demand:
[image: Demand]

When I multiply them I get a mismatch error.

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to get a `Value` from a range that has more than one cell. `Debug.Print Range("B2:B12").Value` gives you the same error, right?

Comment: but how to fix?

Comment: Wouldn't using a formula make more sense?

Comment: which formula?do you mean loop?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788750/fill-formula-down-till-last-row-in-column

Comment: What about `VLookup()`?

Answer (score 0):

### Multiply Same-Sized Ranges Using Worksheet.Evaluate

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    With wb.Worksheets("Revenue")
        .Range("A1").Value = "Year"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Revenue"
        .Range("A2:A12").Value = wb.Worksheets("Price").Range("A2:A12").Value
        .Range("B2:B12").Value = .Evaluate("Price!B2:B12*Demand!B2:B12")
    End With

End Sub
```